# I want to create a form form by inputting a form and a form form using ModelChoiceField

Tags: python, django

Currently, Django is creating a soccer game player information site.
I would like to add a search function that combines pull-down and input form.

As a search method, select the player name category (models.py: player_style) from the pull-down menu, enter the player name (models.py: player_name), and search for the player name.

I used "ModelChoiceField" as the code and entered form.py and views.py, but it stopped due to an error.

Since I'm new to Django, I have a lot of questions, so can you tell me what kind of code to write?

Since the questioner is Japanese, It will be poor English, but thank you.

models.py

```
class Player(models.Model):
    player_style = models.CharField('player_style', max_length=20)
    player_name = models.CharField('player_name', max_length=50)

　　　　　　　　def __str__(self):
　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　return self.player_name
```

form.py

```
    from django import forms
    from django.forms import ModelChoiceField
    from .models import Player
    
    
    class MyModelChoiceField(ModelChoiceField):
      def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return "%i" % obj.player_style + " %s" % obj.player_name
```

views.py

```
from .forms import MyModelChoiceField

def filters(request):
    form = MyModelChoiceField(queryset=Player.objects.all())
    if(request.method == 'POST'):
        form = form()
        player = request.POST['form']
        data = Player.objects.filter(player_name=player)
        msg = 'results：'+str(data.count())
    else:
        msg = 'search words...'
        form = form()
        data = Player.objects.all()
    params = {
        'title': 'Player results',
        'form': form,
        'message':msg,
        'data':data,
    }
    return render(request, 'filters.html', params)
```

filters.html

```
<h3 class="display-4 text-primary">
   {{title}}</h3>
   <p>{{message|safe}}</p>
   <form action="{% url 'filters' %}" method="post">
   {% csrf_token %}
   {{ form.as_p }}
   <tr><th></tr></th>
    <input type="submit" value="click" class="btn btn-primary mt-2"></td></tr>
   </form>
```

Current error

```
File "/Users/--------/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
        response = get_response(request)
      File "/Users/--------/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
        response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
      File "/Users/ーーーーーー/pes2021/pespost/views.py", line 54, in filters
        form = form()
    TypeError: 'MyModelChoiceField' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 0):

so basically you want to give user choice to select in the player name so simply use that in you models.py and will allow user to only pick form that player which you put in choices

```
class Player(models.Model):

    player_n = [
           ('ronaldo', 'ronaldo'),
           ('messi', ''messi'),
     ]

    player_style = models.CharField(max_length=20,)
    player_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=player_n, blank=false)

　　def __str__(self):
　　    return self.player_name
```

and in forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm

class PlayerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Player
        fields = '__all__'
```

and acc to that change you views.py